# Who officially declares cellular network technology?

Tags: network, mobile

There are 4 to 5 cellular network technology

- 1G
- 2G
- 3G
- 4G
- 5G (upcoming maybe)

But who actually defines or officially says that this will be the next cellular technology? which organization or which government agency handles that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, these standards are defined by [ITU-T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Telecommunication_Union), a UN agency.

Comment: For a bit more context, each participating country gets a single vote on whether to adopt a new standard or not. Whereas the IEEE gets a single vote per organization and the IETF is even more lax without an authoritative voting structure.